# PHP - How to know where magic method __call() get called from

Tags: php

Basically, magic method `__call()` will be called if there is no method exists inside class - CMIIW.

For example I have base `Controller` like this

```
class Controller
{
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        //echo error       
    }

    public function foo()
    {
        echo "foo";
    }
}
```

and `AuthController` which extends base `Controller` like this

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return $this->bar();
    }
}
```

My question is how did I know where is it called from? It's for debugging purposes. All I know is magic constant `__LINE__`

Comment: check [debug_stacktrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

Comment: magic constant `__CLASS__`?

Comment: Quick and dirty `throw new Exception('Test');` with error reporting enabled

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya thanks for your info. Its really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking to function `get_called_class`, like this:

```
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    var_dump(get_called_class());
}
```

Will return: `string(14) "AuthController"`

Full code looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Foo;

class Controller
{
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        var_dump(get_called_class());
    }

    public function foo()
    {
        echo "foo";
    }
}

namespace Bar;

class AuthController extends \Foo\Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return $this->bar();
    }
}

$c = new \Bar\AuthController();
$c->create();
```

Please check it out [here](http://rextester.com/MMET88782).

Comment: It returns namespace too) Check it out here: http://rextester.com/MMET88782